# Limit of function with Square roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, rational-functions

I have to evaluate the limit:
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^2-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}-1}$$

I have been instructed to apply the following identity ($ \forall \, a \neq -b$)
$$a-b=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a+b}$$
I am unsure how to proceed. Can you please explain each step?

**EDIT**

My current approach. Please help me out to finish it, and correct me if I am wrong somewhere:
$$(a-b)(a+b)=(a^2-b^2)$$ i.e 
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^2-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}-1}.\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^2+\sqrt{x}}{x^2+\sqrt{x}}$$ =
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^4-x}{x^2\sqrt{x}+x-x^2-\sqrt{x}}$$
How must I proceed from here?

Comment: Have you tried L'hopital's rule?

Comment: I want to apply that formula. No any other rules

Answer (score 9, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^2-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}-1}&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{x}[(\sqrt{x})^3-1]}{\sqrt{x}-1}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}-1)(x+\sqrt{x}+1)}{\sqrt{x}-1}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1}[\sqrt{x}(x+\sqrt{x}+1)]\\
&=3
\end{align}

If we have to use that identity, then we can use $\displaystyle \sqrt{x}-1=\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x}+1}$.

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^2-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}-1}&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{(x^2-\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x}+1)}{x-1}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^2\sqrt{x}+x^2-x-\sqrt{x}}{x-1}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{(x^2-1)\sqrt{x}+x(x-1)}{x-1}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{(x-1)(x+1)\sqrt{x}+x(x-1)}{x-1}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1}[(x+1)\sqrt{x}+x]\\
&=3
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Set $\sqrt x-1=h,$

$\displaystyle \implies x^2-\sqrt x=(1+h)^4-(1+h)=3h+\binom42h^2+\binom43h^3+h^4$

Comment: Of all the answer offered, this is my pick.

Answer (score 2):

I expect that it is hinting that you multiply the top and bottom by ${\sqrt{x}+1}$.

$$\frac{x^2-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}-1} = \frac{(x^2-\sqrt{x})({\sqrt{x}+1})}{(\sqrt{x}-1)({\sqrt{x}+1})} = \frac{(x^2-\sqrt{x})({\sqrt{x}+1})}{{x-1}}$$

Comment: Why I have to multiply by $\sqrt{x}+1$?

Comment: Well, you don't have to but it makes the bottom simpler which is often desirable even if it makes the top messier.  The formula that you give is more often written as $$a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$$ and called the difference of two squares.  A useful trick to remember for simplifying things like this.  It does not always help but sometimes it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use L'hopital's rule:

$$\lim _{x\to 1} \frac{x^2-\sqrt x}{\sqrt x - 1}$$

Apply L'hopital's rule:

$$\lim _{x\to 1}\frac{2x-\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}}{\frac {1}{2 \sqrt x}} = \frac {1.5}{0.5} = 3$$

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the substitution $\sqrt{x}=t$, so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to1}\frac{t^4-t}{t-1}=
\lim_{t\to1}\frac{t(t-1)(t^2+t+1)}{t-1}
$$

With the hint
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}-1}=
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}-1}\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{\sqrt{x}+1}=
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2\sqrt{x}-x+x^2-\sqrt{x}}{x-1}
$$
Now consider
$$
x^2\sqrt{x}-x+x^2-\sqrt{x}=
(x^2-1)\sqrt{x}+x(x-1)=
(x+1)(x-1)\sqrt{x}+x(x-1)
$$